# PHP script times out after exactly 60 seconds or browser prompts to download file

Tags: linux, php, redhat, timeout

We have a Redhat Centos 5.5 system which has a php/mysql application.

After a server restart, we've been seeing some of the 'longer' scripts time out exactly after 60 seconds OR the browser prompts the user to download the php file (which is empty).

Most php scripts are functioning fine, but some are not.

There has been no code change, only the server reboot.

---

Edit1

phpinfo() shows "Loaded Modules" as:

core prefork http_core mod_so mod_auth_basic mod_auth_digest mod_authn_file mod_authn_alias mod_authn_anon mod_authn_dbm mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_authz_owner mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_dbm mod_authz_default util_ldap mod_authnz_ldap mod_include mod_log_config mod_logio mod_env mod_ext_filter mod_mime_magic mod_expires mod_deflate mod_headers mod_usertrack mod_setenvif mod_mime mod_dav mod_status mod_autoindex mod_info mod_dav_fs mod_vhost_alias mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_speling mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_proxy mod_proxy_balancer mod_proxy_ftp mod_proxy_http mod_proxy_connect mod_cache mod_suexec mod_disk_cache mod_file_cache mod_mem_cache mod_cgi mod_version mod_perl mod_php5 mod_proxy_ajp mod_python mod_ssl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be mysql (in case on a remote server is breaking) or someother service on CentOS is killing the thread. I remember SE linux tobe one of the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something was upgraded but never kicked in until it was restarted.  Most obvious would be a new php.ini that set the `max_execution_time` to 60 seconds.

Comment: damn - sorry to not mention earlier - its set to 300

Comment: Are you using "just" CGI, fcgi, or mod_php (and in what server)?  There's a lot of places things can time out...

Comment: Apache's config has it's own TimeOut directive.  Could it have been changed to 60?  Have you looked in apache's error.log for error messages?

Comment: There's a /etc/httpd/logs/error_log which doesnt report any issues.  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf says Timeout 120

Answer (score 0):

On the folders containing the break scripts, do you have an .htaccess file ? Is there a max-execution-time directive in it? Maybe the .htaccess was not read in the old configuration but now it is maybe applied.

Other way: can it be the browser which timeout? Are you sure that your script send some data? Do you have some errors (in Firefox console)?

Comment: Good point - yes, there is an .htaccess, but it doesnt have that, just some url rewriting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default mysql.connect_timeout is 60 in php.ini

Perhaps you are having issues connecting to mysql from your scripts?